# we couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided - Excel

Tags: excel, credentials, webapi, bearer-token

I try to create an overview of my portfolio in excel, therefore I need my api key and other information provided by this [site](https://developers.bitpanda.com/platform/#bitpanda-public-api). I need specific data such as my transactions, assets, trades, etc.
The problem is that I get an 401 error:

[image: Credentials / Access token]

token wrong according to (site mentioned above). Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[image: Access to web content in excel]

Comment: The documentation clearly states that the token is to be passed into a header parameter called `X-API-KEY`, you're passing it into the `Authorization` header.  Change that and see what happens.

Comment: This. I replaced Authorization with X-API-KEY and it worked. Thanks